# Get Matlab data tip value in custom context menu

Tags: matlab, contextmenu, matlab-figure

In Matlab, I would like a context menu to open when I right-click on a data point in a plot. The selected action should call a function where I would like to access the coordinates of the data point for further processing.

The Matlab example is:

```
cm = uicontextmenu(fig);
m = uimenu(cm);
m.Text = "Function description";
m.MenuSelectedFcn = @(src,event)myFunction(src,event);

function myFunction(src,event)
...
end

plot(x, y, "ContextMenu", cm);
```

This works as expected in that myFunction is called when I right click on a data point and click on the action in the context menu. However, I cannot access the x,y values of the data point within myFunction.

Comment: Hello. it might be a little clunky, but Matlab keeps in memory the position where you last pressed a button in a Matlab axes object. have a look at the 'CurrentPoint' property

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to implement a custom function then you can use the [`CurrentPoint` property](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.graphics.axis.axes-properties.html#budumk7-CurrentPoint) of the current axes, so your function would be something like

```
function myFunction(src,event)
    cp = get( gca, 'CurrentPoint' );
    x = cp(1,1);
    y = cp(1,2);
    fprintf( 'x = %.2f, y = %.2f\n', x, y );
end
```

In use:

[image: custom callback]

---

**However**, the functionality you're describing can be achieved natively (without a custom callback) using the datatip cursor and the `Export Cursor Data To Workspace...` option.

Other advantages include

- Easier to right click because you can do so anywhere with the data tip cursor enabled rather than having to hit the line exactly.
- You can view and move the selected points before they're exported
- You can select multiple points and they are all exported.

[image: data tip]

You have even more options using the in-built brushing tool, where you can brush areas of your data and then

- You can export, copy, or display data in the command window
- You can quickly highlight whole regions of data
- Slightly more fiddly than the data tips as you have to right-click the actual brushed data to get the right click menu, the same as the custom callback.

[image: brush]